# Rails 4.1 counter cache not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, counter-cache

This counter cache does not seem to be working correctly, although to my knowledge I have done everything correctly.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :search_stats, counter_cache: true
end
```

migration:

```
class AddSearchStatsCounterCacheToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :search_stats_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false

    User.reset_column_information
    User.find_each do |u|
      u.update_attribute(:search_stats_count, u.search_stats.count)
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :search_stats_count
  end
end
```

Why does this not update the counter?

```
user = User.find( user_id )
user.search_stats.create!( search_params: search_params.to_json )
```

Comment: Check your logs, are you getting an Unpermitted params error for the `search_stats_count`?

Comment: Sorry. I just realized what I did wrong here. I need a beer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serious brain fart. The `counter_cache` option should be on the `belong_to` not the `has_many`. Explicitly stated in the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)